# PHP MySQL CSV file import page

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to create a CSV file PHP upload page, that takes an endusers file and uploads it into a new table in a mysql DB. The user specifies the table name via a text box thats value is stored using session and the csv file is selected by the end user via a filename input.

I have the connection.php working and I have embedded the below code into a page, but I keep getting a syntax error on the mysql query. Can I do those two actions together (i.e. create the table and import), or do they need to be done separately?

Any thoughts welcomed..

```
<?php
session_start();

include "scripts/db_connection.php"; //Connect to Database

$_SESSION['tablename'] = $tablename;

$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE '$tablename'"; //empty the table of its current records
mysql_query($deleterecords);



//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}

//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");



while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="CREATE TABLE $tablename; INSERT into $tablename(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";

//view upload form
}else {

print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='Upload_mobile.php' method='post'>";

print "Name of table to upload to:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='text' name='tablename'><br />\n";

print "File name to import:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>
```

Update: Ok I've used mysqli multi query, but I'm confused as the page/script runs without errors but doesn't create a table based on $tablename or throw an error. Anyideas how to troubleshoot this?

New updated code below:

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 include "scripts/db_connection.php"; //Connect to Database

 $_SESSION['tablename'] = $tablename;

 $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE '$tablename'"; //empty the table of its current records
 mysqli_query($deleterecords);



 //Upload File
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}

//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");



while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="CREATE TABLE $tablename; INSERT into     $tablename(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

    mysqli_multi_query($import) or die(mysqli_error());
   }

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";

//view upload form
 }else {

print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='Upload_mobile.php' method='post'>";

print "Name of table to upload to:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='text' name='tablename'><br />\n";

print "File name to import:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}


?>
```

UPDATE2: I've tried to come at this from a different angle with the below using "LOAD DATA INFILE" but I'm still not getting anywhere. Firstly it isn't creating a table but the connection to the DB is working. I'm not sure if this attempt to create the table is failing and then that obviously stops the rest of it. Thoughts welcomed!?!

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 //connect to DB

 $_SESSION['Tablename'] = $Tablename;
 $_SESSION['filename'] = $filename;


 }

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $createtable = mysqli_query($db, "CREATE TABLE $Tablename");
 mysqli_query($createtable) or die(mysqli_error());

 $importfile = "
    LOAD DATA INFILE '".$filename."'
           INTO TABLE results  CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES (name, description, price, shipping, quantity);
    ";

     mysqli_query($importfile) or die(mysqli_error());

    }

 {

print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='Upload_mobile.php' method='post'>";

print "Name of table to upload to:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='text' name='Tablename'><br />\n";

print "File name to import:<br />\n";

print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}


?>
```

Comment: Please look into `htmlspecialchars` and `PDO`-`prepared statements`.

Comment: Sorry why is htmlspecialchars relevant?

Comment: If the filename or the file contents you're displaying contains Javascript and/or HTML you'll be in trouble. The security term for this is _Cross Site Scripting_. Your SQL Query is also vulnerable to _SQL Injection_. It's not relevant for the core question you had but it is relevant in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multi-query going here. That means a string with a semi-colon then other statements in the string.

Either separate them out and call them individually, or use [mysqli multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

You ought to be off the `mysql*` library anyway and onto `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Ok I've used mysqli multi query but I'm confused as the page/script runs without errors but doesn't create a table based on $tablename.